# What is the next step after server responds user has logged in from my api

Tags: ios

I've made an api for my iOS application where users can login and register. Now the api is ready, and gives responses to my application, where I need to do stuff with.

How do I handle the response from the server when the user is logged in? The server sends `"UserLoggedIn"` in an `NSString`.

Do I need to make a singleton class for this, where I store a boolean with `userLoggedin` and their password and username for when the user opens the app again after shutting it down, so the user will still be logged in. And when the user presses logout, the credentials will be deleted from the singleton class. Or isn't this the way I should go?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing usernames and passwords on a client, you could use a session token. A session token could be a random string that the server generates upon a successful authentication and returns back to the client. The client can then use that session token to communicate with the server, and the server knows who's asking (and perhaps validate permissions etc).

You can store the session token in the keychain or in the not-so-secure NSUserDefaults so that the app can be closed but the session is kept alive.

When the app is opened up again, you could present the "logged in state" of the app if there is a session token present and in the background ask the server if the session token is still valid (if it turns out it's not valid, you can logout the user).

When the user logs out, simply delete the session token from the device and tell the server to invalidate the token.

You're asking about the singleton pattern, and sure - creating a singleton to manage the session to the server is something you could do to make it easier for the rest of your app. `[MySessionManager shared].isUserLoggedIn` is an example of a method that class could provide, together with stuff like "Logout" and "Login".

Comment: Is there a technical name for that session token? And also, so if i understood it right, I should make a new field in my users sql database, with a name "token" lets say and put one there in if it's empty on logging in. And store that token in my iOS app in the keychain. After logging in, I can `set and get` information by just using the 'token' that has been made for the user in that app trough my api?

Comment: I guess the technical name is "Session token". I suggest having the tokens in another db-table with a reference to the user table (because you might want information like 'createdat', 'validuntil', 'createdbyip' etc.

Comment: Okay so in my new table, i'll put, (token, userid, token created, tokenvaliduntil, createdbyip). Many thanks already!